# Delete record with out page refresh in codeigniter is not working

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

Hi all i am trying to delete my  record from datatable with out page refresh in codeigniter i have used ajax i don't know where i have done mistake its not deleting the record

Below  is the my view:

```
    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        if (!empty($employees)) {
                            foreach ($employees as $emp) {
                                 ?>

                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $emp->emp_name; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $emp->salary; ?></td>
                                    <td class='text-center'>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs confirmation" name="login"><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class='text-center'>
                                     <button type="submit"  onClick="return ConfirmDelete()" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs confirmation empdelete" id="<?php echo $emp->id;?>"><i class='fas fa-times'></i></button>
                                     </td>
                               </tr>

                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".empdelete").click(function(e){
    alert();
   e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
      alert();
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?=site_url('Employee/delete');?>",
      cache: false,
      data: {id:$(this).attr("id")}, // since, you need to delete post of particular id
      success: function(data) {
         if (data){
            alert("Success");
         } else {
             alert("ERROR");
         }
         return false;

       }
   });
});
});
</script>
```

Here is the my controller:

```
  function delete()  
  {
    $id = $this->input->post('id'); // get the post data
    $empdelete=$this->Emp_model->delete($id);
    if($empdelete){
        echo true;
    } else {
        echo false;
    }
 }
```

Here is my model's method delete:

```
function delete($id)
{ 
$sql  = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE id=?";
return $this->db->query($sql,array($id));
```

}

Can any one help me how can i do that with out page refresh i want to delete my record.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure you have id in your ajax code check by  `console.log($(this).attr("id"));`

Comment: where i have to check this inside success fucntion?

Comment: after this the click : `$(".empdelete").click(function(e){ console.log($(this).attr("id"));` and see your console for the result

Comment: first of all i am not even getting alert after  this which i have placed $(".empdelete").click(function(e){

Comment: you have to delete data when user click confirm in your `ConfirmDelete()` method otherwise there will be no use of `ConfirmDelete` method

Comment: can you please help me where i have done mistake

Comment: Obviously in your ajax ,try by removing `onClick="return ConfirmDelete()"` or simply use `ConfirmDelete()` method to delete the record

Comment: i am getting success alert and when i click on ok its not happening anything..

Comment: u have to add a click event on ok just like u do before with `empdelete` class means add `empdelete` class to your ok button

Comment: i didn't understand how to add can you please show me how we can give

Comment: show your `ConfirmDelete` method and html also

Comment: function ConfirmDelete()
    {
        var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        if (x)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        function ConfirmDelete() {
            var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
            if (x)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        $(".empdelete").click(function (e) {
            var obj = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();
            //alert(); what's this do?
            if (ConfirmDelete() == false) {
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({
                //alert(); this can't go here
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('Employee/delete'); ?>",
                cache: false,
                data: {id: $(this).attr("id")},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('ajax returned: ');
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data) {
                        obj.closest('tr').remove();
                        alert("Success");
                    } else {
                        alert("ERROR");
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and remove HTML onClick:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs confirmation empdelete" id="<?php echo $emp->id;?>"><i class='fas fa-times'></i></button>
```

Comment: when i clickon delete it is asking are you sure you want to delete so when i click on ok it is asking agin success alert so when i click ok from success nothing is happening

Comment: in this code there is only 1 alert, nothing success related

Comment: i have copied your code but still getting same result

Comment: wait nevermind, see success alert in ajax success function. what do you mean nothing is happening? that means that it should be deleted other wise it would alert ERROR.

Comment: getting error from this linde  url: "<php echo site_url('Employee/delete'); ?>", in console

Comment: fixed `<php` should be `<?php` please copy and try again

Comment: stilll getting success alert

Comment: that's intended when it succeeds no? works exactly as expected on my setup

Comment: even thats what i didnt understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177541/discussion-between-alex-and-suresh).

Comment: hi i have one doubt may i ask

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

Your button should be like this :

```
<button type="button"  onClick="return ConfirmDelete(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs confirmation empdelete" data-id="<?=$emp->id;?>"><i class='fas fa-times'></i></button>
```

Your ajax code should be like this :

```
function ConfirmDelete(obj) 
{ 
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"); 
  if (x == true) 
  {
    var id = $(obj).data('id');
    alert(id);
    if (id != '')
    {
      //do you ajax here
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<php echo site_url('Employee/delete'); ?>",
          cache: false,
          data: {'id': id},
          success: function (data) {
              console.log('ajax returned: ');
              console.log(data);
              if (data) {
                  alert("Success");
              } else {
                  alert("ERROR");
              }
              return false;
          }
      });
    }
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
}
```

Your controller should be like this :

```
function delete()  
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id'); // get the post data
    $empdelete = $this->Emp_model->delete($id);
    if($empdelete)
    {
        echo true;
    } else 
    {
        echo false;
    }
    exit;
}
```

Your delete method should be like this :

```
function delete($id)
{ 
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('employees');
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

Comment: ok change `function  ConfirmDelete(this)`  to `function ConfirmDelete(obj)` , from  `this` to `obj` see my updated answer

Comment: no errors from control but still not deleting record

Comment: did u get `alert(id);`

Comment: make sure u have id in `data-id="<?=$emp->id;?>"` in your button attr

Comment: hi i have one doubt may i ask

Comment: @Pradeep Sir what does it means `return $this->db->affected_rows();`??

Comment: @KUMAR Displays the number of affected rows. For more  https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html